# How to make a docker compose file for an existing image?

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, docker-compose

What I am trying to do is use a Docker image I found online [timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3](https://hub.docker.com/r/timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3/), and run my ionic project within Docker. I want to mount my ionic project in Docker and forward my ports so I can run the emulator in a browser.

I want to ask how do I create a docker-compose.yml file for an existing container?

I found a Docker image [timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3](https://hub.docker.com/r/timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3/) that I want to run, which has the correct version of the tools that I want.

Now I want to create a compose file to forward the ports to my computer, and mount the project files. I create this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8100:8100"
     - "35729:35729"
    volumes:
     - /Users/leetcat/project/:/project
```

But every time I try to do `docker-compose up` I get the error:

```
 ~/user: docker-compose up     
Building web
Step 1/6 : FROM timwiconsulting:ionic-v1.3
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: pull access denied for timwiconsulting, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login
```

I am doing something wrong. I think I want to be creating a `docker-compose.yml` file for the container [timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3](https://hub.docker.com/r/timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3/). Feel free to tell me I am totally off the mark with what docker is.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM timwiconsulting:ionic-v1.3

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /project

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /project

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
# RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8100
EXPOSE 35729

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
# CMD ["python", "app.py"]

# docker exec -it <container_hash> /bin/bash/
```

Comment: `timwiconsulting:ionic-v1.3` != `timwiconsulting/ionic-v1.3`

Comment: I understand that. But it is an error that is being reported. I did not type that.

Comment: Ah I see, that is in the `Dockerfile` that is the issue!